# Problem with FileWriter into multiple files in Java

Tags: java, xml, freemarker, filewriter

I'm using java with freemarker to generate HTML files through the FTL (the template file) and XML. I got the result in multiple files but each file contains the whole result. I want each file to contain its own result. To give you more details, take a look at this part of my java code: (the solution should be so easy but I can't find it)

```
static void freemarkerDo(Map datamodel, String template) throws Exception{
  try {
      File file = new File("Avis.xml");
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = db.parse(file);
      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Avis");

      Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

      Template tpl = cfg.getTemplate(template);



      for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

        Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

        if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
            NodeList flNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Filename");
            Element flNmElmnt = (Element) flNmElmntLst.item(0);
            NodeList flNm = flNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(((Node) flNm.item(0)).getNodeValue()+".html");

            try {
                tpl.process(datamodel, writer);
                }
            finally{
                writer.close();
                    }
                                                        }



      }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm very confused with what your trying to do.  What do you mean you want each file with its own result?  Should each file have it owns data model?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what this method does or where datamodel is set, however it would appear to me that you are passing the entire datamodel, so that would explain why you have the entire datamodel in each file.

```
tpl.process(datamodel, writer); // does what, with what?
```

What do you see when you debug your code?

Comment: This method process a template using freemarker and generate the result.
tpl.process(datamodel, writer); this merge the template with the data model

Comment: Yes, but in your code it's always the same template. Same template + same datamodel = same result.